# Scala pattern matching filename and possible extension

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

For extracting a filename and its possible extension considered

```
val pat = """(.*)[.]([^.]*)""".r
"myfilename.myext" match { 
  case pat(fname,ext) => doSomething(fname, ext) 
}
```

However the pattern matching fails for a missing extension,

```
"myfilename" match { 
  case pat(fname,ext) => doSomethingElse(fname) 
}
```

What is a brief and elegant approach to extracting a filename with (possible) extension ?

Comment: does """(.*)[.]?([^.]*)""" and matching case pat(fnane,"") work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not to excited about this pattern, and even less excited about the use of `null`, but this one should work:

```
val pattern = "(.*?)(?:[.]([^.]*))?".r
"myfilename.ext" match {
  case pattern(name, null) => println(s"$name")
  case pattern(name, ext) => println(s"$name.$ext")
}
```